# Controlling Pepper using ROS

Tags: ros, navigation, pepper

I am trying to implement FastSLAM 1.0 and I am using sensory and control data acquired from Pepper via ROS to evaluate my implementation. However I am having major issues when I try and control Pepper's movement via ROS.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.

I set up my NAOqi bridging using the NAOqi driver command

```
$ roslaunch naoqi_driver naoqi_driver.launch nao_ip:=<MY_ROBOT_IP> roscore_ip:=localhost network_interface:=wlp1s0
```

(I was originally using the pepper_bringup package to set up the brigde, however ran into errors stating I had not set up the PYTHONPATH to the NAOqi API properly

```
$ roslaunch pepper_bringup pepper_full_py.launch nao_ip:=<yourRobotIP> roscore_ip:=<roscore_ip>)
```

I then run RViz, having sourced my setup.bash

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

I then find and load pre-configured RViz configuration in my catkin workspace into RViz

```
src/pepper_robot/pepper_description/config/pepper.rviz
```

From there I am able to see Pepper in RViz along with the camera images and sonar .

Then I set up moveit so I can control Pepper with the commands

```
$ export NAO_IP=<YOUR_ROBOT_IP>

$ roslaunch pepper_dcm_bringup pepper_bringup.launch

$ roslaunch pepper_moveit_config moveit_planner.launch
```

This starts the Moveit RViz GUI where I start my planning of the route I want Pepper to execute, following [this documentation](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_moveit_config).

However whenever I execute it, it always fails and the error message I get from the terminal says that it cannot access any controls, (I thought I had a screen shot saved of the message, however I don't, but will be working on Pepper again tomorrow, so can acquire one then)

Has anyone got experience controlling Pepper using ROS and Moveit and may have had similar issues which they managed to resolve?

Otherwise has anyone any tips on how to control Pepper through other means? I have found documentation on ways to control it with a joystick, again if anyone has tried this and been successful, I would be grateful for some advise on how they managed to get it working.

Comment: Did you follow [the tutorial](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_moveit_config/blob/master/README.rst)? Specifically, did you `Wait until it is ready` between the `pepper_dcm_bringup` and `pepper_moveit_config` commands? What IP address are you using?

Comment: I'll caution you too that this is *Robotics*; you may be better off asking this question at [so].

Comment: Try running each of your `roslaunch` commands with the `--screen` option to see if anything is failing. Also, it probably goes without saying, but I'll say it anyway: Make sure you're running those two `roslaunch` commands in different terminals.